# Is there any reason why $N\ kg^{-1}$ shouldn't be used as the units for acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, units

When doing a calculation involving a force of $F=1000$ N on a mass of $m=100$ kg we use the formula $a=\frac{F}{m}$

$$a=\frac{F}{m}=\frac{1000\ N}{100\ kg}=10\ N\ kg^{-1}$$

Is there any reason why I should convert this to $m\ s^{-2}$ or is it perfectly reasonable to leave it in this form?

Comment: What exactly is the issue here ? N/kg = m/s², since N = kg*m/s². I think writing it as m/s² however is more common since it is in "SI base units" (meter and second), whereas newton is a "SI derived unit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no fundamental reason why you should convert it to ms$^{-2}$, as Nkg$^{-1}$ is entirely equivalent. However, from a practical point of view, ms$^{-2}$ is the most widely used unit for acceleration, so using ms$^{-2}$ will help others understand your work better.

Another way of putting this is that "m" and "s" are SI base units, whereas "N" is a SI derived unit. Some may argue that using SI base units is preferred, but again, all a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

N/kg is equivalent to m/s$^2$ so it is fine to use as it as a unit of acceleration. If you have an acceleration of 10 N/kg, that means the net force on you is 10 N for every individual kg of your mass.

In fact, I often use this convention with my students learning gravitational field/acceleration. While most intro students will only think of $g$ as the "gravitational acceleration," it is in fact the gravitational *field*, telling us that Earth's gravity exerts 9.8 N of force for every kg of mass in an object.